# innerHTML output value is duplicated using vuejs

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I´m currently learning vue, and came accross issue when I rander an HTML text.
This is my component template, its an WYSIWYG.

```
<template>
 <div id='editor_container'>
  <slot name="header" />
  <div id='editor' ref='editorPost'></div>
  <slot name="footer" />
 </div>
</template>
```

import { tempDOC } from './helpers/docFormats'

I created simple function to send data for testing.

```
      templateEdit () {
        const editor = this.$refs.editorPost.innerHTML = tempDOC
      }
```

On my tempDOC.js    file I export string:

*export const tempDOC = `Please enter your name to continue`*

When I render innerHTML content from tempDOC into the $refs.editorPost(editor WYSIWYG), the value is getting duplicated.

### Editor result:

Please enter your name to continue

---

Please enter your name to continue

---

Bellow is the inspect HTML.

```
<div id="editor" spellcheck="false" contenteditable="true">
<p>Please enter   your name to continue</p>

Please enter your name to continue
</div>
```

Not sure whey the values are getting duplicated,I debug app using chrome and I see this is being called after my function. I don´t have that piece code on my side.

```
    this._observer = new MutationObserver(function (mutations) {
  _this._handleMutations(mutations);
});
```

}

Comment: how are you consuming this component? I see two `slot`'s but i'm not sure how you're using them. can you reproduce this issue in jsfiddle or codepen?

Comment: How are you calling `templateEdit`?

Answer (score 1):

It is a bad practice to use refs for this purpose. You should use the `Data` function of Vue to make a variable and change it / reach it's value through the vue `this`.

```
<template>
 <div id='editor_container'>
  <slot name="header" />
  <div id='editor'>{{editorPost}}</div>
  <slot name="footer" />
 </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                editorPost: "this is the inner HTML",
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

Now change the `editorPost` to change the `innerHTML`.

Comment: can you please help, how to get ```innerHTML``` of some div by id in ```editorPost``` ?